# "Not a typewriter" AVRDude error on Android

Tags: android, usb, libusb, avrdude

I have received a file descriptor for a [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus) device from an Android app (using  [getFileDescriptor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#getFileDescriptor%28%29)), sent it via JNI in native code and received it in a child process (AVRDude) via a Unix socket and tried to use for uploading.

So I'm getting a "**Not a typewriter**" error. Does it mean that file descriptor was passed incorrectly (it is a positive int and it is not equal to -1 after receiving)? Or can there be another error? Can it be a permissions issue (though permissions to UsbDevice is granted and passing via a socket seems to hold permissions, the device is not rooted)?

The code used (`ser_posix.c` in AVRDude 5_11_0 sources):

```
fprintf(stdout, "Try to set baud = %i for fd = %i", baud, usbfd);
if (!isatty(usbfd)) { // Error here!
    fprintf(stderr, "!isatty\n");
    return -ENOTTY;
}
```

Right after receiving from the socket file descriptor is checked to be valid (and I believe it is):

```
if (!(fcntl(usbfd, F_GETFL) != -1 || errno != EBADF)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid file descriptor %d, - %s", usbfd, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

Originally the file descriptor in ser_posix is received like that (and I believe it's working):

```
fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

In my implementation I use the file descriptor from the Android app instead. Is it what's expected?

Comment: tested on 2 devices with USB-Host support of different manufacturers and Android OS versions (4.0.4 and 4.1) - the same error

Comment: file descriptor is guaranteed to be not changed between getting from socket and using for setting baud rate

Comment: removing "isatty" does not help since i'm getting the same error on later operations (set baud rate actually) with serial